# Validation error message in InputText for Integer field?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In my page i have a inputtextbox which is used

```
 <h:inputText id="min" maxlength="5" value="#{beanName.minLength}"
  binding="#{mininput}" >
    <rf:validator event="blur" />
 </h:inputText>
```

I am giving value like `12.12` i am getting below error message

> contentform:equipFeatAdd:min: '12.12' must be a number between
>   -2147483648 and 2147483647 Example: 9346

I am not able to understand why it is showing message for float value its due to binding field in `Integer` ?

**EDIT:-**

Binding varaible is used in another InputText like this

```
 <h:inputText id="max" maxlength="5" value="#{beanName.maxLength}"><f:validator validatorId=" portal.validators.NumberComparisonValidator" />
<f:attribute name="mininput" value="#{mininput}" />
<rf:validator event="blur" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: @BalusC After removing `binding` no message is coming .`binding` because i have to validate two field with each other value so this field i am passing to the another inputtexbox like `<f:attribute name="mininput" value="#{mininput}" />` for a Validator created by me

Comment: Yes total two  Inputbox component using this

Comment: @Balusc Look like here misinterpretation edit my question I am not using same binding name in two different component .Edited question as well.